# Find files in a directory by Date

Tags: c#, .net, linq

We are working with an external accounts program who save "printed documents" on a network share. Each "printed document" in the directory contains 3 files.

- XML file - Contains information about who printed the document, etc
- Datareport file - Contain the actual data for the report layout file
- Layout file - The report layout

We have a customer who has 120,000 files in the directory.

Currently when the user want to see all the "printed documents" the software will loop all the files in the directory and then read each XML file and see if the report is for this user....... this takes 10 mins to read each time.

We are trying to create a faster solution.

The only idea I can think of is to loop the files and put the contents (file name, XML details) into a database table and record the "Last Scanned Date".
The next time i loop through the files i can loop through and dismiss any items that are less than the "Last Scanned Date" or use a Linq query!? (borrowed from another post)

```
DateTime LastCreatedDate = Properties.Settings.Default["LastDateTime"].ToDateTime();
var filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"\\Printed\Reports\", "*_*.xml").Select(p => new {Path = p, Date = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(p)})
    .OrderBy(x=>x.Date)
    .Where(x=>x.Date>=LastCreatedDate);
```

Is there a quicker solution?

Answer (score 1):

You could set up a Windows service which detects additions to the folder and then updates the database with the new entries. Thereafter, any queries on documents printed would be at the cost of a database query only.

Comment: I can't think of the advantage to doing this from a service, rather than in his application.

Comment: The benefit is that this would happen as soon as a change is made to the folder rather than when the user makes a query. That way, the database is always up-to-date. It it therefore the lowest performance solution at the point of the query. As mentioned [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa365261%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it is possible to set up a trigger if a folder changes.

Comment: The application can watch for changes to the folder just as easily as a service can. Then you don't need to wrastle with interprocess communication and all that.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your use case, it looked like what you were asking for was to have a system where a user could ask for all of their printed documents. I didn't see where date was a part of the solution.

I can think of multiple quick solutions:

1. Have a subdirectory for each user. As new files enter the main directory, have the file parsed and copied to the appropriate user subdirectories (allows for a file being associated to multiple users). This has the benefit of limiting the number of files per directory.
2. Have a mapping (either through a DB, flat XML file, or flat XML file per user) which maps a file to the user. Then update the mapping with each new file, while also containing a listing of files which have already been processed so that you don't reprocess the file.
3. Research document management database, if a more robust solution is desired. If you want to be able to searching for a lot of different types of meta-data, then a document management database would be a good idea.

NOTE - For ideas 1 and 2, you could process the new files as either part of a service, a task, or whenever a user makes a request for documents.

Comment: The date was used so that i didn't have to go back to the database each time to see if this file had been processed already. I could just get a list of files from x date and check those

Comment: Does that mean that you already have a scanning program that stores the meta-data for a file so that you can quickly get the listing of files associated to the user? As such, you are just looking for a solution that prevents you from re-scanning files? If so, the quickest solution I can think of is having a "Processed" subdirectory where scanned files are moved to. So, every time you scan the directory it will only have unscanned files. You may want further subdirectories to avoid having a massive number of files in one directory. I have had performance issues with that.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's the parsing of the XML that is taking a long time?  You could do a basic "grep" of all the files for the user name/id and then do the actual XML parsing on just the matching files.